# Ayuda con construcción de consulta sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Quiero construir un SQL para corregir las ocurrencias de un error que sucede con un programa.
El programa registra pesajes de un producto en distintas etapas de su producción. Por la naturaleza de la producción el producto pierde peso entre las sucesivas etapas, sin embargo, por errores operativos puede darse que una etapa anterior tenga menos peso que una posterior, ésto puede ser corregido manualmente por el usuario pero el programa tiene un bug desconosido (y no reparable por mi) que termina dejando mas de un pesaje para el mismo producto en el mismo punto, y hay que eliminar todos los que no sean "mas acordes". El criterio del mas acorde es simple, el que tenga menor diferencia con el punto siguiente, esta diferencia sea "Racional" (menor a un parametro), o en su defecto (de no existir pesajes dentro del rango), el que tenga peso 0.

Aqui tienen datos de prueba:
[image: Datos de prueba]
Generados a partir de la siguiente consulta:

```
DECLARE @Fecha as datetime
DECLARE @PerdidaMaxima as smallint
SET @Fecha = '20180223'
SET @PerdidaMaxima = 15

Select T1.ClavePrimariaAutonumerada, T1.FechaProduccion, T1.NumeroDePieza, T1.NumeroDeSubPiesa, T1.Peso Peso1, T2.Peso Peso2, ROUND(T1.Peso/(COALESCE(NullIf(T2.Peso,0),T1.Peso)/100)-100,2) Perdida1,ROUND(100-T2.Peso/(COALESCE(NullIf(T1.Peso,0),T2.Peso)/100),2) Perdida2
 FROM TablaDePesos1 T1
INNER JOIN
 TablaDePesos2 T2
ON 
 T2.Activo = 1
 and T2.FechaProduccion = T1.FechaProduccion
 and T2.NumeroDePieza = T1.NumeroDePieza
 and T2.NumeroDeSubPiesa= T1.NumeroDeSubPiesa
WHERE
 T1.Activo = 1 and
 T1.FechaProduccion = @Fecha

 AND (T1.NumeroDePieza = 1028 AND T1.NumeroDeSubPiesa = 3) --Caso Presentado, este filtro no iria
```

Las perdidas son calculos (uno basandonos en el Peso1, otro basandonos en el Peso2) de los pesos perdidos. Activo es el campo con el que se elimina logicamente un registro, `FechaProduccion`, `NumeroDePieza` y `NumeroDeSubPiesa` son las "Claves primarias logicas" por lo cual no deberian repetirse, pero como es el caso, en `TablaDePesos1`se repite.

En este ejemplo deberíamos descartar todas las lineas a exepcion de la segunda, dado que ésta está dentro del rango (Menor a `@PerdidaMaxima` que es 15) y es la mas cercana al peso siguiente (no asi la primer linea), ademas de no tener "perdida negativa" (como la tercer linea) (lo cual es el primordial error) y "es mejor tener peso que usar el 0" (que descarta la cuarta linea).

No he encontrado una solución decente mas que comenzar a hacer subconsulta tras subconsulta, junto a algún UNION hasta dar con el que necesito conservar para luego hacer un update junto a un WHERE ID NOT IN ... nada muy optimizado.

Agradezco a todo el que lo intente, seguro ponga recompensa al respecto porque es importante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La verdad es que sin tener datos de prueba de tus tablas es difícil simular tu problema. Sin embargo, podrías probar usando `CROSS APPLY` (aunque no va a ser rápido):

```
DECLARE @Fecha datetime;
DECLARE @PerdidaMaxima smallint;
SET @Fecha = '20180223';
SET @PerdidaMaxima = 15;

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  T1.ClavePrimariaAutonumerada, 
            T1.FechaProduccion, 
            T1.NumeroDePieza, 
            T1.NumeroDeSubPiesa, 
            T1.Peso Peso1, 
            T2.Peso Peso2, 
            ROUND(T1.Peso/(COALESCE(NULLIF(T2.Peso,0),T1.Peso)/100)-100,2) Perdida1,
            ROUND(100-T2.Peso/(COALESCE(NULLIF(T1.Peso,0),T2.Peso)/100),2) Perdida2
    FROM TablaDePesos1 T1
    INNER JOIN TablaDePesos2 T2
        ON T2.Activo = 1
        AND T2.FechaProduccion = T1.FechaProduccion
        AND T2.NumeroDePieza = T1.NumeroDePieza
        AND T2.NumeroDeSubPiesa= T1.NumeroDeSubPiesa
    WHERE T1.Activo = 1 
    AND T1.FechaProduccion = @Fecha
    AND (T1.NumeroDePieza = 1028 AND T1.NumeroDeSubPiesa = 3) --Caso Presentado, este filtro no iria
)
SELECT A.*
FROM CTE A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM CTE
             WHERE FechaProduccion = A.FechaProduccion
             AND NumeroDePieza = A.NumeroDePieza
             AND NumeroDeSubPiesa = A.NumeroDeSubPiesa
             ORDER BY   CASE WHEN Perdida1 < 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
                        CASE WHEN Perdida1 < @PerdidaMaxima THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
                        Peso1 DESC)
;
```

Comment: Muchas, muchísimas gracias realmente. El uso del CASE dentro del Order By era la clave que no lograba descifrar, excelente y exquisito en su simpleza. Debí hacerle algunos cambios pero es lo que necesitada, no lo marco como correcta porque no puedo sumarle una recompensa hasta mañana. Por otro lado, pese a resolver "el registro correcto"  no se me ocurre mas que utilizar ese "Select top 1" como subconsulta del update que borra "los otros" (`where not Clave = (select top 1 Clave...` , Me explico?), hay una mejor manera? dado que no creo que se pueda hacer un update a un `With`...

Comment: @RicardoGalain Lo del `UPDATE` no lo entiendo muy bien...cuál tabla necesitas actualizar?

Comment: La `T1`, digamos que debo cambiar el  `Activo = 1` de esas lineas, por la que retorna el `CROSS APPLY`. Supongo que usar la subconsulta que retorna lo mismo que el `CROSS APPLY` dentro del WHERE del UPDATE de T1 deberia funcionar. Pero hay una manera mejor?

Comment: Creo que lo más sencillo sería insertar el resultado de la query anterior en una tabla temporal y luego hacer el update cruzando con la tabla T1